# Laravel serializeDate ignored when using JsonResource

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 10.10.1 and as title suggests, the `serializeDate` is not being called when using `JsonResource`, while the documentation clearly states that it will be. When I call the serialization directly, the `serializeDate` is called properly, ex.: `$model->toArray()`.

Model.php:

```
    protected $casts = [
        'received_at' => 'datetime:d-m-Y H:i'
    ];

    protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date): string
    {
        return $date->format('d-m-Y H:i');
    }
```

ReadController.php:

```
    public function __invoke(ReadRequest $request, Model $model): Resource
    {
        return new Resource($model);
    }
```

Resource.php:

```
class Resource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'received_at' => $this->received_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Result:

```
received_at: "2023-07-22T09:46:00.000000Z"
```

Expected result:

```
received_at: "22-07-2023 09:46"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please note that when I try one of these, it works properly:

- new Resource($report) (as printout of dd())
- response($report->toJson())
- response($report->toArray())
- response($report)

But I do not want to use these, I want to use as I wrote above in `ReadController.php`. Is that even possible?

Comment: AFAK `serializeDate` only affects the model itself when it is serialized. You can just do `$this->received_at->format('d-m-Y H:i')` in the resource though

Comment: I thought that `JsonResource` serializes the model before it is returned, since it does call the `toArray($request)` function. Is that not the case? Doing as you suggested is not an option since the code I pasted is mere example, I have datetime parameters all over the API and keeping those in sync will take considerable time.

Comment: The `JsonResource` is the thing that gets serialised. It does not serialise the model. Their point is so you can create different JSON "views" of your models

Comment: So I have no other choice but to use either `->format('d-m-Y H:i')` per field or use `response()->json($model)`? I am properly puzzled by this behaviour, especially since in their docs they are mentioning that we should use JsonResponse to have more control than using `->toJson()` or other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#:%7E:text=When%20defining%20a,or%20JSON%3A)

> When defining a date or datetime cast, you may also specify the date's format. This format will be used when the model is serialized to an array or JSON

You can go with the below workaround:

```php
class Resource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        $serializedData = $this->resource->toArray();
        return [
            'received_at' => $serializedData['received_at'],
        ];
    }
}
```

with `$this->resource`, you can access the original model object and call `toArray`.

Also, the default JsonResource is the same.

```php
    public function toArray(Request $request)
    {
        if (is_null($this->resource)) {
            return [];
        }

        return is_array($this->resource)
            ? $this->resource
            : $this->resource->toArray();
    }
```

If resource is not an array, then it will call `toArray` method on the resource.

Comment: If the JsonResource calls `toArray()`, why it's not calling the `serializeDate` as well? Since if I manually call the `toArray` or `toJson`, the dates will be formatted, but if I let JsonResource do that for me, the serializeDate is ignored. I also tried the formatting from docs you quoted (aka: 'received_at' => 'datetime:d-m-Y H:i'), and it's also ignored when using JsonResource.

Comment: I don't know why they didn't do that, but from my point of view, it's a good point.
Assume that you have a Laravel application as an API service and this app includes an admin panel. And users' timezone is important because we have users worldwide (like Calendly).
I want to format(cast) dates in the admin panel but for rest apis we need to pass the TZ format to client, So that would be good for this situation.
Also, unlike other casting types, you don't need to casted dates and datetimes in your logic(like controllers), and you will need a Carbon object.

Comment: Sounds logical and it's quite possible that I imagined how it works, wrongly. Docs, despite there's a lot of them, are confusing.